# Opening Microsoft Office Word in command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

Why does opening Microsoft Office Word in command prompt work by using "**start winword**" instead of "**start microsoftword**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program name (which you would see in a directory listing) is `winword.exe`. Windows 'knows' to add the file type, so you just have to type `winword` to run it.

You could type out the entire name if you prefer: `winword.exe`. It will run just the same.